# Android MapView Bitmap Problem

Tags: android

The following Code should speed up my MapView because I'm handling a large set of routes. Unfortunately the "else" part does not draw anything. Could somebody help me to understand this. Thx

```
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow, long when) {

    if ((bmap == null) || (lastLatSpan != mapv.getLatitudeSpan())) {
        // bitmap is null - so we haven't previously drawn the path, OR
        // the map has been zoomed in/out, so we're gonna re-draw it anyway
        // (alternatively, I could have tried scaling the bitmap... might
        // be worth investigating if that is more efficient)

        // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view
        Canvas offscreencanvas = new Canvas();
        bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapv.getWidth(), mapv.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        offscreencanvas.setBitmap(bmap);

        Path path = null;

        Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();

        // lastLatSpan = mapv.getLatitudeSpan();

        for (int j = 0; j < mTourenArray.length; j++) {
            GeoPoint[] route = GeoPointFactory
                    .createGeoPointArray(mTourenArray[j].getGeoPointArray());
            defaultColor = mTourenArray[j].getColorByCat();
            path = new Path();
            Paint polyPaint = new Paint();
            polyPaint.setColor(defaultColor);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
                GeoPoint gp1 = route[i];
                GeoPoint gp2 = route[i + 1];

                if (shadow == false) {
                    polyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    Point point = new Point();
                    projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
                    // mode=1&#65306;start
                    if (i == 0) {
                        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y
                                - mRadius, point.x + mRadius, point.y
                                + mRadius);
                        // start point
                        canvas.drawOval(oval, polyPaint);
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);

                        path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
                    }
                    /* mode=3&#65306;end */
                    else if (i == route.length - 2) {
                        /* the last path */
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);

                        RectF oval = new RectF(point2.x - mRadius, point2.y
                                - mRadius, point2.x + mRadius, point2.y
                                + mRadius);
                        /* end point */
                        polyPaint.setAlpha(255);
                        offscreencanvas.drawOval(oval, polyPaint);
                    }
                    // mode=2&#65306;path
                    else if (i < route.length - 2 & i != 0) {
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);

                    }

                }
            }

            // create an off-screen canvas to prepare new bitmap, and
            // draw path on to it
            polyPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            polyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            polyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            polyPaint
                    .setAlpha(defaultColor == Color.parseColor("#6C8715") ? 220
                            : 120);

            offscreencanvas.drawPath(path, polyPaint);

        } // Outer For End

        // draw the bitmap of the path onto my map view's canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, null);

        // make a note of where we put the bitmap, so we know how
        // much we
        // we need to move it by if the user pans the map
        mapStartPosition = projection.fromPixels(0, 0);

    } else {
        // as we're in onDraw, we think the user has panned/moved the map
        // if we're in here, the zoom level hasn't changed, and
        // we've already got a bitmap with a drawing of the route path

        Projection proj = mapv.getProjection();

        // where has the mapview been panned to?
        Point offsetPt = new Point();

        proj.toPixels(mapStartPosition, offsetPt);
        Paint tmpPaint = new Paint();

        // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view
        // draw the bitmap in the new correct location
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, offsetPt.x, offsetPt.y, tmpPaint);

    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow, when);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx etteyafed for your answer

the problem was

```
if (shadow == false)
```

the working code here:

```
if (shadow == false) {
        if ((bmap == null) || (lastLatSpan != mapv.getLatitudeSpan()) || true) {
            // bitmap is null - so we haven't previously drawn the path, OR
            // the map has been zoomed in/out, so we're gonna re-draw it
            // anyway
            // (alternatively, I could have tried scaling the bitmap...
            // might
            // be worth investigating if that is more efficient)

            // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view
            Canvas offscreencanvas = new Canvas();
            bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapv.getWidth(), mapv.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bmap.copy(Config.ARGB_4444, true);
            offscreencanvas.setBitmap(bmap);
            mCanvas = offscreencanvas;

            Path path = null;

            Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();

            lastLatSpan = mapv.getLatitudeSpan();

            for (int j = 0; j < mTourenArray.length; j++) {
                GeoPoint[] route = GeoPointFactory
                        .createGeoPointArray(mTourenArray[j]
                                .getGeoPointArray());
                defaultColor = mTourenArray[j].getColorByCat();
                path = new Path();
                Paint polyPaint = new Paint();
                polyPaint.setColor(defaultColor);

                for (int i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
                    GeoPoint gp1 = route[i];
                    GeoPoint gp2 = route[i + 1];

                    polyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    Point point = new Point();
                    projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
                    // mode=1&#65306;start
                    if (i == 0) {
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);

                        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y
                                - mRadius, point.x + mRadius, point.y
                                + mRadius);
                        // start point
                        offscreencanvas.drawOval(oval, polyPaint);

                        path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
                    }
                    /* mode=3&#65306;end */
                    else if (i == route.length - 2) {
                        /* the last path */
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);

                        RectF oval = new RectF(point2.x - mRadius, point2.y
                                - mRadius, point2.x + mRadius, point2.y
                                + mRadius);
                        /* end point */
                        polyPaint.setAlpha(255);
                        offscreencanvas.drawOval(oval, polyPaint);
                    }
                    // mode=2&#65306;path
                    else if (i < route.length - 2 & i != 0) {
                        Point point2 = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
                        path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);

                    }

                }

                // create an off-screen canvas to prepare new bitmap, and
                // draw path on to it
                polyPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                polyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                polyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                polyPaint.setAlpha(defaultColor == Color
                        .parseColor("#6C8715") ? 220 : 120);

                offscreencanvas.drawPath(path, polyPaint);

            } // Outer For End

            // draw the bitmap of the path onto my map view's canvas
            // And set these pixels to destination bitmap:
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, null);

            panAfterZoom(mapv, 600);
            // make a note of where we put the bitmap, so we know how
            // much we
            // we need to move it by if the user pans the map
            mapStartPosition = projection.fromPixels(0, 0);

        } else {
            // as we're in onDraw, we think the user has panned/moved the
            // map
            // if we're in here, the zoom level hasn't changed, and
            // we've already got a bitmap with a drawing of the route path

            Projection proj = mapv.getProjection();

            // where has the mapview been panned to?
            Point offsetPt = new Point();

            proj.toPixels(mapStartPosition, offsetPt);

            // start point

            // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view
            // draw the bitmap in the new correct location
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, offsetPt.x, offsetPt.y, null);


        }
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow, when);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious but i am not sure what the context of your method is (or what some of your member fields are holding) but there are some things that you might check. 
  Does mapStartPosition equal the current position?
  I am not familiar with the method signature for that super.draw(Canvas,MapView, boolean, long) call, but in my experience its not usually necessary/helpful to call the super.draw method directly. Doc says that MapView inherits the draw from view which takes only Canvas as an arg so I am not sure what you are doing there. Generally I just call draw on the canvas or other drawable object.

I know that this isn't really an "answer" but maybe it will help. Good luck!